# XPath selection by innertext

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract an element with a particular innertext from a parsed XML document.  I know that I can select an element that has a child with a particular innertext using `//myparent[mychild='foo']`, but I actually just want to select the "mychild" element in this example.

```html
<myparent>
  <mychild>
    foo
  </mychild>
</myparent>
```

What would be the XPath query for "foo" that would return the "mychild" node?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
//myparent/mychild[text() = 'foo']
```

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut for the `self` axis:

```
//myparent/mychild[. = 'foo']
```

Comment: or //myparent[mychild = 'foo']

Comment: @Matt : if OP wants to select the mychild element, then your solution won't work, it will select the myparent element.

Answer (score 7):

Matt said it, but the full solution:

```
//myparent[mychild='foo']/mychild
```

Comment: it searches all child nodes of "myparent" where any "mychild" of "myparent" has "foo" as inner text.

Answer (score 6):

You might consider using the `contains` function to return true/false if the test was found like so:

```
//mychild[contains(text(),'foo')]
```

See [XSLT, XPath, and XQuery Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp) for functions reference

Comment: +1: in my case `//h3[contains(text(),"In This Week’s Podcast")]` found element and `//h3[text()="In This Week’s Podcast"]` did not; I only tested it on Chrome.

Comment: To Marcelo Scofano Diniz: yes, because text() has to exactly equal with the string. Any leading or closing space, pagebreak, tab or whitespace character makes that to false.

Answer (score 3):

As per the HTML:

```
<myparent>
  <mychild>
    foo
  </mychild>
</myparent>
```

The `<mychild>` element with text as **foo** is within it's parent `<myparent>` tag and the text contains **leading** and **trailing** *white space* characters.

So to select the `<mychild>` element you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  //myparent/mychild[normalize-space()='foo']
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  //myparent/mychild[contains(., 'foo')]
  ```

Ignoring the parent `<myparent>` tag you can also use:

- Using `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  //mychild[normalize-space()='foo']
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  //mychild[contains(., 'foo')]
  ```